# Python installing new library

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a newbie to python and I want to install a new library on python 3.5.2

Given a *.py file, what should I do to install it?

I am trying to install 'cs1graphics' module from its website [cs1graphics.org](https://cs1graphics.org) and downloaded "cs1graphics.py" file.

What should I do with the file to code with the module?
(I already tried command `python cs1graphics.py` but it didn't worked).

Comment: which library to be specific ?

Comment: mention library name you want to install..

Comment: It is 'cs1graphics' http://www.cs1graphics.org/

Comment: add detail explanation in question

Comment: i'm asking how to install it...I don't know even how to start it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `windows` open command prompt and install `*.py` as:

```
python setup.py install
```

Here my installable module is `setup.py` just replace `setup.py` with your `.py`.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is put the *.py file in some directory which is included in the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`.  If you need to add a new directory to PYTHONPATH on Windows:

```
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\Some\Path\To\Lib
```

Or on Linux:

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/some/path/to/lib"
```